# Opengl Multiple model rendering overlapping each other rather than normally displaying

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am using opengl and eclipse to build an android app that loads ply models and renders it . But when i tried rendering two files together one being transparent and the other being opaque the result i got is rather abnormal ..

[front view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNWHa.png)

as you can see the hair is owerlapping the face rather than simply displaying

pls help ..

Comment: my first guess would be that the depth test is not enabled. in any case please provide more information, e.g. code snippets of your rendering.

Comment: I have enable depth test on the body alpha blending on the hair ..as it is required

Comment: i think you still need to enable depth test on the hair, otherwise, well, the hair will be 100% in front of the body.

Comment: if i enable depth test then i cant use blending

Answer (score 0):

for the body, you'll want to disable blending and enable depth testing, like you said.

for the hair, you need to enable alpha blending of course but still need to enable depth testing. otherwise, all hair will be visible regardless of whether it's behind the body or not.

but, if the frontmost strand of hair is rendered first, all hair behind that won't get drawn at all since the depth test now fails.

the solution is to have depth testing enabled but disable writing to the depth buffer with `glDepthMask`. This will render everything that's in front of the body, regardless of the ordering, but nothing that's behind it.